# Auto Backup gone crazy

Tags: google-plus

My android phone has gone completely crazy by backing up hundreds of images onto my Google + photos. These are not photos from my phone camera but some sort of random pictures of all sorts of crap! It's driving me mad and it's filling up my online storage with rubbish.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

If the rubbish/random images aren’t in the camera roll on your phone, how are you determining they are coming from your phone?

I’m wondering if one of two things is going on:

1. you’ve not signed out of google+ on some other device and that device is doing the uploading (sold or given away a phone or computer? used a machine or phone of someone else’s?) or
2. you have a security app installed and the app has been activated and taking random images (and helpfully sending them up to google) to help you nab the “thief”.